# No output after compiling and executing the code

Tags: fortran

I'm new to fortran and i'm trying to execute this as an output.

```
program write2file
implicit none
! open file
 open (10, file='output_file.txt', status='unknown')

! write to file
  write(10, *) 'Hello World!'

! close file
close(10)
end program write2file
```

I'm running it on Linux and I have tried to use this statement to compile and execute the output, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the 'output_file.txt'

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: How did you compile it? It works and runs fine on my Linux machine with both gfortran and ifort. And were there any errors when you ran it?

Comment: i used the command ifort -o output hi.f90 to compile. No errors were observed. In fact, there was another file which is the 'output' but i cant understand the output, at all. And i'm suppose that it should give me 'output_file.txt' ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I have tried your method, its still the same. is it due to the way i execute it? 'ifort -o output hi.f90'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment rather than an answer but I feel in need of better formatting.  After you execute the command

```
ifort -o output hi.f90
```

you should have an executable called `output` in your current working directory.  To execute that executable execute the command

```
./output
```

which will, if you are successful, write the output you want to wherever the current version of the program directs it.

Reading your comments makes me suspect that you think the command

```
ifort -o output hi.f90
```

ought to execute your program and cause the creation of the output requested.  But that command just compiles your sources (in the file `hi.f90`) into the executable called `ouptut`.  Is this the first time you've used a compiler ?

Comment: Not the first time, but i'm not very sure of the commands that it. anyway. Thank you so much! That should be the command to output the file. :)