# gfortran not printing but no compiler errors

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm new to working with Fortran and was trying to compile my first script and have `gfortran` installed on my Mac, but when I try and compile my script via terminal nothing happens. This might be a bigger issue than I hope but here is my setup.

I changed the PATH away from the MacPorts version of GCC because I was getting errors as well, so I'm trying to use the Homebrew version.

When checking

```
$ which gfortran
>>> /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0/bin/gfortran

$ gfortran --version
>>> GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0) 9.3.0
```

My Fortran HelloWorld.f90 script has this:

```
program HelloWorld
    implicit none
    CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: hello 
    hello = "Hello World!"
    print *,hello
end program HelloWorld
```

In my terminal I run the script:

```
$ gfortran HelloWorld.f90
```

No errors appear but nothing returns either...

I also have tried in my Eclipse environment but same issues occur.

Again this is my first experience with Fortran so I'm sure there is something missing. Am I using the correct file extension? Any insight would be incredibly helpful right now and I'm happy to provide any info desired to help, thanks!

Comment: Although the linked question is about using ifort to compile, the answer is just as applicable for gfortran.  You can use `./a.out` as in the previous comment, or use the `-o HellowWorld` option to give the created program a different name.  Either way, once you've _compiled_ your program with gfortran, you then need to _run_ it.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much. I did see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975906/no-output-after-compiling-and-executing-the-code but thought it didn't apply to me. My mistake.